# File Get and put contents to Text file with new line

Tags: php

I have two files

File1.php and File2.php

```
$hello = file_get_contents("file1.php");
file_put_contents("hello.txt",$hello);
```

file1.php contains some example texts like below

```
hello \r\n hi \r\n how are you.
```

What i need is when I put contents to hello.txt , I want the words to appear in new line like below

```
hello 
hi
how are you.
```

I tried to use \r\n and \n but nothing works

**Note:** file1.php is the file_get_contents of another page source..i can only replace `<br>` tag with  `\r\n` and this is just an example. I have some other complex part to do.

Comment: I think you need to do something like this `file_put_contents("hello.txt",$hello) . "\n";`

Comment: When you're replacing, are you making sure to use double quotes `"` and not single quotes `'`? `$string = "Hello\r\nWorld";` will be `Hello[NEWLINE]World` whereas `$string = 'Hello\r\nWorld';` will be `Hello\r\nWorld` (the literal characters);

Comment: nope..$hello contains multiple break lines..how will this work

Comment: @VishnuVishwa see my suggestion above. Btw, does your file already contain the characters `\r\n` and you need that replaced? I don't quite understand your question.

Comment: @Fred your suggestion above does not make sense, if you want to add `\n` then you have to do it like this `file_put_contents("hello.txt",$hello."\n");` but to be honest the whole question isn't clear since I think that the OP is confused between new lines and hard codes `'\r\n'`. So I think he should give us a link on what he has, and then we could give some proper advice...

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV that's what I meant lol - thanks, and yes, the OP will have to be clearer. I forgot to move the `)` at the end. My bad.

Comment: @VishnuVishwa Your question isn't clear, are the `\r\n` provided in your example hardcoded or are they actually newlines ? What are you trying to achieve anyways ?

Comment: \r\n are actually the one i replaced with <br>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should put something at the end of each line,

then you can replace it whit :

```
   str_replace
```

function, i think this will work

```
str_replace('[EndOfLine]', "\r\n", $string);
```

Answer (score 3):

Do a [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$hello = str_replace('\r\n', "\r\n", $hello)
```

Note that single quote and double quotes are different... Read the difference here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score -1):

Make your File1.php to contain this text

```
hello 
hi
how are you.
```

and your code would work perfectly!

Comment: nope its the file_get_contents of another page source..i can only replace <br> tag with  \r\n